# ActionBar icons not showing after the update of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I don't know if anyone of you guys are facing the same problem. I have added the strings, done the programming in menu_main.xml, added holo dark theme but none of that seems to be working. Before the update everything was working just fine. 
Help me guys...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_share" android:title="@string/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" /></menu>

<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="action_share">Share</string>
<string name="action_search">Search</string>
```

Comment: There are no icons declared in the menu, add: `android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"` in every item in which you want to see an icon.

Comment: Still it is suppose to show the text but its not